# How can I add new scene in inventor 2022

Tags: c#, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

I am able to open presentation document using C# now I want to create new scene in Inventor 2022 using C#.

Scene1

[image: scene1]

As you can see in the scene1 image I want to add my newly created scene below scene1. My expected outcome should be like this

Expected Outcome

[image: Expected Outcome]